# VPLS connection

Tags: cisco, routing, router, ethernet, vpls

My Network is as follows.

11.11.11.1 (connected interface g0/1)--(CE IP= 10.10.10.1)R1 == VPLS_Cloud == R2 (CE ip=10.10.10.2)

I can ping from router (ping 10.10.10.2 works)
ping 10.10.10.2 source g0/1 doesnt work for some reason.

```
R1#sh arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  10.10.10.1              -   XXXX.XXXX.cd00  ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/0.555
Internet  10.10.10.2             16   XXXX.XXXX.XXXX ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/0.555
Internet  12.12.12.1              -   XXXX.XXXX.XXXX ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1
Internet  12.12.12.2             28   XXXX.XXXX.XXXX ARPA   GigabitEthernet0/1
```

Can Someone figure out what the issue is ?

Comment: You probably don't have a route, or the far end doesn't have a route back.

Comment: Why should I have a route to a connected interface ? This is like 4 computers connected to a router right ?

Comment: 11.11.11.1 is on a different subnet -- How does R2 know how to get there?

Comment: Issue sorted.. you are correct. missing route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R2 doesn't have a route to 11.11.11.0, so it doesn't know where to send the echo reply.  Add a route with the next hop on 10.10.10.1.